# Storing Data into Variables to Update Firebase

Tags: swift, uitableview, variables, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For the app Im designing, I've created 3 variables to store information:

```
var name: String?
var city: String?
var state: String?
```

The variables are meant to edit the information stored within each text field of each cell in my table view, from firebase.
For instance: The name field has the user's name that was stored in the database after the user signed up for an account. Code is located in cellforRowAt:

```
/Sets the text to the user information.
            if (firstfewCells.ttField.tag == 0)
            {
                firstfewCells.ttField?.text = user.name
                self.name = firstfewCells.ttField.text!
            }
            else if (firstfewCells.ttField.tag == 1)
            {
                firstfewCells.ttField?.text = user.city
                self.city = firstfewCells.ttField.text!
            }
            else 
            {
                firstfewCells.ttField?.text = user.state
                self.state = firstfewCells.ttField.text!
            }
```

Once the user is finish updating the textfields, a method that updates the database is called once the user presses the "Save" button:

```
func justsave()
{
    let uniqueUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    //Update
    ref.child(uniqueUserID!).child("name").setValue(name)
    ref.child(uniqueUserID!).child("city").setValue(city)
    ref.child(uniqueUserID!).child("state").setValue(state)}
```

Whenever I check firebase, the child nodes aren't updating. Whats the reason behind this? I've used updateChildValues as well and Im getting the same results. I don't think that the variables are picking up an values in cellForRowAt. What should I do so that they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where do you update your variables `name`, `city`, `state`?

Your code in `cellforRowAt` sets the cell text fields to the local variables, and immediately sets them back again - there's nothing here to update the variables after you have edited them.

I would implement the UITextFieldDelegate in your ViewController, give each of the TextFields a unique tag and then process the input before you get to the Save button

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason)
{
    switch textField.tag
    {
    case TextFieldNameTag:
        name = textField.text
    case TextFieldCityTag:
        city = textField.text
    case TextFieldStateTag:
        state = textField.text
    default:
        // Shouldn't ever get here, but you need a default
        break
    }
}
```

Have a look for textFieldDelegate tutorials - there are a lot around.

Comment: How would I go about updating them after they're edited? I thought that setting the local variables equal to the textfield would update them. Sorry, im still fairly new to swift @Russell

Comment: using the code you recommended, the variables are still coming up as nil

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in textFieldDidEndEditing?  Are you retrieving the text field values ?